# UISearchBar with a custom UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I would like the following to work in iOS4:

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    controller.searchResultsTableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
}
```

However, the `UITableView` doesn't support it. How can I change the `searchResultsTableView` so that it uses a `UDTableView` (https://github.com/ud7/UDTableView-allowsMultipleSelection) instead of `UITableView`?

Comment: try let your class implement this protocol: `UISearchDisplayDelegate`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to use a subclass, but I got multiple section working in search mode without UDTableView:

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {

    if ([controller.searchResultsTableView respondsToSelector:@selector(allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing)]) {
        controller.searchResultsTableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
    }
    else {
        controller.searchResultsTableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```